# Libre Office document window not seen

Tags: libreoffice

Sometimes when I open Libre Writer document it doesn't show its window.

But I can see from the launcher that in fact it is open.

When I opened multiple documents, the same behaviour - if I click on the Writer's launcher, invisible windows hover - only close buttons are seen.

The problem was solved after I deleted configuration files of libreoffice from /home/.config directory and entered through Libre Office from the Dash.

But, what caused the problem?

Answer (score 18):

**Resize the window using unity keyboard shortcuts**

This happened to me in LibreOffice Calc on Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Then move your mouse to desired window size.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Good to know about this alt+space feature!

Answer (score 7):

Following steps might help

1. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate to LibreOffice
2. Change the view to 'full screen' using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>
3. Use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to see all workspaces
4. Click on LibreOffice, drag it below until you see the maximize option on top left
5. double-click somewhere on the work space with LibreOffice
6. Upon maximizing the workspace, click on the maximize button in LibreOffice (top left)

You should get your LibreOffice normal view back.

Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Indeed, playing with `shift+ctrl+j` allowed the resize/reduce/close window buttons to be back... I have no idea why Open Office didn't show these buttons on 1st start and needs such madness to make them appear : )

Comment: `shift-ctrl+j` and then just closing the window with `alt+f4` fixed it for me. Writer UI showed up properly after.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone with troubleshooting, but you can re-size those windows to get them to display.

(I had this happen in Impress, and I could not for the life of me figure out what was wrong for two weeks).

Comment: I had the same problem and resizing the window using keyboard shortcuts helped me (i had no resize buttons) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To make the window visible is "easy", but it is annoying to do it every time.

### **To prevent it for the next time:**

You have to reset the value `FactoryWindowAttributes`:

#### **1. Solution**:

1. Open `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`
2. delete all lines containing `FactoryWindowAttributes`

#### 2. Solution:

1. Open LibreOffice `Tools` > `Options` > `LibreOffice` > `Advanced` > `Open Expert Configuration` (German: `Extras` > `Optionen` > `LibreOffice` > `Erweitert` > `Experteneinstellungen...`)
2. `FactoryWindowAttributes` and click search
3. Reset the values of `TextDocument` and `SpreadsheetDocument`

#### source

Solution1:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1159445/676490
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1159645/676490

Solution2:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1315527/676490

Answer (score 0):

new on Ubuntu 22.04 I had this problem as well. Either full screen or minimize. No size adjustment...
After reading all these nice tips, one thing sorted it for me:
Under "Extras - options - view: **disable** the hardware acceleration!
Hope it helps others.