# Libre office dots between words / not displaying documents properly

Tags: libreoffice, document

First LibreOffice opened with nothing but the title bar every time, regardless of the file. Here's a picture of what I mean[!here's a picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1xY1.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1xY1.jpg)

[This person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611094/libre-office-document-window-not-seen) seemed to have a similar problem, but they fixed it by resizing, I haven't got resize buttons, but sometimes using keyboard shortcuts I manage to display my document. It looks [image: like this] All those dots
between the words should not be there.. But sometimes the keyboard shortcuts don't work at all.

I've tried reinstalling libreoffice and I've tried swapping from Ubuntu to Xubuntu..

Comment: ahh alt + F8 worked.

Comment: I see nothing about resizing in the linked post, only about removing local settings.

Comment: Sorry, it was a response to the linked post where it was fixed by resizing. Not in the post itself.

Comment: Ok, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

For the former issue:

Launch LibreOffice with the method of your choice. Use the Keyboard combination <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to turn off full screen mode so that the menu bar appears.

For the latter issue:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> Turns off non-printing characters. You can also do this from the menu by unchecking View-> Non printing characters. This should resolve the dots in your document.

Tested on Libre Office version 4.2.8.2.

Sources:

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Full_Screen
LibreOffice menus
Testing.

Comment: Maybe it would have worked, but I am back to my original problem of the document not showing at all and now the keyboard shortcuts don't work. I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling it but it didn't work.

Comment: @Rabbit Please [edit] your question to reflect your current situation or you are likely to continue to get answers that resolve what appears to be the case.

Comment: Does this problem occur when you attempt to open a document or when you launch Libre Office from the launcher or both? Again [edit] your question with the new information so as not to waste time. Thank you for helping us help you!