# LibreOffice settings don't fit the screen

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, display-resolution, 22.04

On an older laptop running Kubuntu 22.04 I cannot access the options in the LibreOffice settings, even with largest resolution and small fonts

[image]

This happened on the same computer even with Plasma settings but that was fixed in newer versions of Plasma.

It must be related to the relatively small resolution of the screen (1366x768) but is there a solution? I don't think I had this problem in Xfce, as on the same machine I was able to customize LOWriter toolbars in the past...

It is a non-resisable window, but such windows - like those of Plasma Settings, where I had a similar problem in the past - for this very reason should keep their entire frame within the screen, and let their content be accessed by scrolling/moving the scrollbar to the right of the window:

[image]

What the scrollbar cannot affect - the OK, Apply etc buttons at the bottom - should stay within the screen area...

Comment: Minimal requirements indicate that a screen resolution of 1024×768 should be enough: https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/system-requirements/

Comment: @FedKad - does that mean that LO is to blame (so I should ask them) or that there is some problem with the display of this GTK UI on plasma?

Comment: I don't want to misguide you, but if the settings window you are talking about is not resizable, you should ask at LO forum or file a bug (and expect it to be solved in 10 years or so!) 

Comment: @FedKad - there is a workaround that I posted - just move the window...

Comment: @FedKad - `if the settings window... is not resizable, you should ...file a bug` : the problem is not that the window is not resizable, but that it pushes out of the screen, which still might be a Plasma-related problem. Plasma Settings windows are not resizable either but stay within the screen.

Comment: The window you are talking about is from the **Tools** → **Customize...** menu option. I tested it in my environment (LO 7.3.4.2, Ubuntu 22.04 & FHD display) and its minimum window size is 817 × 743. So, I think, it should fit into a 1024 × 768 display.

Comment: @FedKad - You mean it fits fine on your display Gnome, which means this is not LO's fault, but a problem that could be triangulated between GTK on Plasma, my vIdeo card and its drivers? :) I imagine some setting like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1315527/925128) might count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution is just a workaround.

Testing on newer Plasma (5.25.3, in Fedora 36) I can confirm this is not happening, so it's not a LO bug. (I have posted the image with proper display in the question).

---

Workaround: the window can be *moved*: it's the window manager action that can stick the window to the mouse and drag it outside the screen to one side so that the options of the opposite side become accessible.

The action is accessible from the window titlebar (by default right-click) or the menu button, or with Meta+W shortcut (by default, editable in Kwin shortcuts)

[image]

[image]