# LibreOffice Display problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, icons, libreoffice

Suddenly, when I open a new spreadsheet in LO, I only get the icon in the margin, showing a spreadsheet is open, but it will not display.

This suddenly started happening. I can click on the icon, but the document does not display. It does not seem to affect writer, but sofar it affects spreadsheets, but seemingly not Impress.

It feels as if this is some setting in Ubuntu. Still don't know what's causing this, but the minimized spreadsheet went to my left monitor, which is why I did not see it, it was sitting right beside other desktop icons.
For me the problem is now somewhat solved. I know what to do, but still clueless as to how this happens.

Comment: Sometimes, libreoffice windows have a minimal size (barely greater than a pixel). Try to close all other windows, and try to locate this. Then, make the window size bigger.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1335709/124466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Libreoffice calc initial window size problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159377/libreoffice-calc-initial-window-size-problem)